# difficulty signing up for meetup api

Tags: meetup, oauth

I used to use the meetup API from time to time.

and i'd use a command like this

`curl "https://api.meetup.com/2/rsvp/" -k -F "event_id=123456789" -F "rsvp=yes" -F "key=1f382f48c6f4a0b6ca7e4b6a454b4a"`

But that is no longer working.

```
C:\Users\user>curl.exe "https://api.meetup.com/2/rsvp/" -k -F "event_id=987641234" -F "rsvp=yes" -F "key=abcdef1238c1234567abcdefb4f"`

{"details":"API requests must be key-signed, oauth-signed, or accompanied by a key: https:\/\/www.meetup.com\/meetup_api\/docs\/#authentication","code":"not_authorized","problem":"You are not authorized to make that request"}
```

see I get the error "You are not authorized to make that request"

It used to work

If I go https://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/  then I see a link to OAuth customers, that may be relevant to me. So I click https://secure.meetup.com/meetup_api/oauth_consumers/    and then I click "create one now"

They want a "application website", that doesn't really apply to me. I guess I could say N/A, i'm not sure if that's ok.

Then it says Redirect URL.  I have no idea what to enter here.

Comment: why has this question got two close votes?

Comment: i'm thinking the answer might be to make a google sites site, for eg personal programming projects, use that for application url and redirect url.